# Blur animation during variable change angularjs

Tags: angularjs, animation

Hello I've got an array

```
$scope.items = ['Informacje', 'Opis', 'Cena', 'Podsumowanie' ];
```

And in view I am changing selected one by `ng-click` directive and displaying only selected one by `ng-if` directive.

```
<div ng-if="selected.item == 'Informacje'">
```

Now I want to have a blur in/out quick animation when clicking button with `ng-click` directive which change `selected.item`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this class to `ng-if` (animate-if) div. So the HTML will be

```
<div ng-if="selected.item == 'Informacje'" class="animate-if">
```

<kbd>**Plunkr Demo**</kbd>

Another demo.

<kbd>**Plunkr Demo**</kbd>

Also please include the library [`ng-animate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

**CSS:**

```
.animate-if {
  background:white;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}

.animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave {
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}

.animate-if.ng-enter,
.animate-if.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}

.animate-if.ng-leave,
.animate-if.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

**References:**

1. [ng-if documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Comment: @BT101 I updated my answer with documentation for ng-animate, there `ng-show/hide` is supported! Try to implement this in your code!